# Question about p-value

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value

I need someone proficient enough in stats to help me clear up some confusion.
The p-value is a conditional profitability. Given a null hypothesis to be true (mean difference in two groups to be 0), the p-value is the probability that chance alone caused the next observation to be outside of the statistical model. When the p-value is small, that is greater evidence against the null. Is up till that point correct?

Comment: Yes, it is. "probability [of] obtaining a result more extreme" [given that the null is true] is better formulation of "chance alone caused the next observation to be outside of the statistical model".

Comment: Or to rephrase @January, it is the probability of observing a result as or more extreme, by chance alone, when the null hypothesis is true